# JSON distinguishing between objects and primitives

Tags: java, json, object, jackson, primitive

Currently dealing with a java project using Jackson for JSON R/W and I happened upon a strange issue.

When I originally wrote out the current JSON representation of my data, it included an array of Double's(big D object doubles), and after realizing that I didn't really need to deal with all that autoboxing I switched the object over to using double's(small d primitives). Now I get an error thrown whenever I try to read in the old JSON saying:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: N/A (through reference chain: recognition.AverageFace["doublePixels"])
```

I was thinking of just manually changing the representation in the JSON, but I realized tha tI had no idea as to how the difference between a Double and a double is represented within JSON. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you write a small program that writes out one of each?  Then you'll see ...

Comment: Add a portion of the problematic JSON to your question, as well as the code you are using to parse it.

Comment: I just ran into this same error when trying to serialize an object.  Any thoughts on what this means?

Comment: @Webnet Eventually took it to mean I should use GSON instead of Jackson. Avoided the problem.